# Is there a way to construct HTML/CSS in an HTML email such that if image X does not load, text Y will appear?

Tags: html, image, html-email

I'm looking for something a little more sophisticated than the alt="Newsletter Heading text" attribute of `<img>` tag.

So if the Masthead.png image doesn't load for whatever reason, I want the display text, say Font: 60px Helvetica Neue Black, Helvetica, ..., Sans Serif text-align: center to appear in the middle of the table cell that is my masthead instead of just the alt text in some small default font in top right corner. One idea I had was to use to put the image on-top of the text display but I don't know if z-depth is something I can use in email HTML(?4)?

Comment: You may be interested in digging into how [Mozify](http://www.emailonacid.com/email-preview/mozify) works - they're doing *very* neat things with image blocking replacement.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/SCfsD/1/

---

You can specify styles like `font-family`, `font-size` etc.. for `<img>` tags and they'll be applied for the alt text if it is ever displayed. You can use:

```
<img src="booya.png" alt="Hello World" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 29px; font-weight: bold">
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/9r2us/

*Note*: Since your usecase involves emails, you should inline the styles. I guess you already know that.

Comment: Yes I know about inline and thank-you for your answer. Actually going to try using Fractal a web portal that converts Divs and CSS into tables and CSS & inline styles — see how it goes first time trialling it.

Comment: In your JS-fiddle demo I could get big text but no vertical or horizontal centering of text. Something dumb I'm missing?http://jsfiddle.net/SCfsD/

Comment: Please see the updated demo with the required styles added for vert/horiz alignment.

Comment: That's not doing the centring in either axis, it's pretty much the same code as my fork of your original… maybe not possible within the <img> tag?

Comment: It is possible. Which browser are you testing with. I tested it only in FF.

Comment: Safari and Chrome. If it's not working in them I don't like it's chances in Outlook, Gmail web client etc.Check in FF on OS X Lion and yes it's working there.

Comment: I'm wondering if there isn't some other conceptually different approach, even a bit of JS that asks is the image loaded if not kill the element and insert display <p>s

Comment: It is very unlikely that JS will run in email clients

Comment: Okay. Anything else from left field?